# Bootstrap 4 carousel next and prev slides don't work

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm trying to solve an weird issue for a school group project on my own, but I'm at wit's end. Essentially, I have a Bootstrap 4 Carousel with three images. Though one of the images is displayed, you can't advance to the next or previous slides. The initial webpage is launched using php as follows:

```
<?php

//require_once('connection.php');

if (isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $controller = $_GET['controller'];
    $action     = $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $controller = 'static';
    $action     = 'landing';
}

require_once('views/layout.php');
?>
```

The landing page launches `layout.php` (which has the Bootstrap, jQuery, popper and other JavaScript files and `landing.php` (which has the carousel code:

#### landing.php:

```
<div id="main_container" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="body" class="container">
        <p>Stuff about how great the application is.</p>
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" content="width=device-width data-ride="carousel">

            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- The slideshow -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="./views/images/kids_kites.png" alt="Los Angeles">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                        <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./views/images/kids_playing.png" alt="Chicago">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Chicago</h3>
                        <p>We had such great pizza in CHI!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./views/images/kids_swing.png" alt="New York">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>New York</h3>
                        <p>It is too crowded!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="?controller=static&action=searchEvents" id="searchEvents">Search Events</a>
</div>
```

#### layout.php

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Kamps For Kids</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/styles/styles.css">
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="views/scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once "templates/header.php";
require_once "templates/footer.php";
require_once "routes.php";
?>
<div id="id01" class="modal">
    <!--action_page.php is the php file which will perform user validation when the 'submit' button is clicked -->
    <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="img-container">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <div><img src="./views/images/KamparoosLogo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"></div>
            <img src="./views/images/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">

            <div>
                <!-- Add icon library from font-awesome -->
                <link rel="stylesheet"
                      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

                <!-- Add font awesome icons -->
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="user-name" required>

            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="container" style="background-color:#FAFC2F">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancel-btn">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="id02" class="modal">
    <!--action_page.php is the php file which will perform user validation when the 'submit' button is clicked -->
    <form class="modal-content animate" name="registrationForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"
          action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="img-container">
            <h3>Registration Form</h3>
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <div><img src="./views/images/KamparoosLogo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"></div>
            <img src="./views/images/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            <div>
                <!-- Add icon library from font-awesome -->
                <link rel="stylesheet"
                      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" name="firstName"
                       required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lastName"
                       required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter email address"
                       name="emailAddress" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Enter 10 digit phone number"
                       name="phoneNumber" required
                       pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}"
                       size="10">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="numOfKids">Number of Kids </label>
                <select name="numOfKids" id="numOfKids">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password"
                       required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Re-enter password"
                       name="confirmPassword" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="userRole">Register as </label>
                <select name="userRole" id="userRole" required>
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="user">Individual User</option>
                    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                    <option value="organization">Organization</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-success"
        ">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, the modal with close
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    // Get the modal
    var modalTwo = document.getElementById('id02');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, the modal with close
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modalTwo) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're interested, the project is being saved in a GitHub repository at : https://github.com/ad410project/ad410project I'm sure it's possible some crazy php issue, but any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to fix it and I have raised a pull request. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Rohit. I basically merged the carousel back into landing.php and it started to work again. I don't know if the php coding was acting up   but since that's were the Bootstrap 4 and jQuery links were . . well. I just worried that the team with "undo" the changes I've made via PHP . . . Don't get me wrong: I love PHP . . . when it's used the right way!

Comment: No it was not PHP problem the links were not in place.